# Magento multistore different manufacturers

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I’ve magento 1.7 running multi-stores and I need to display for the different stores different brands/manufacturers

at the moment I use this code:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
$manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
?>

<?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>
<a href="/manufacturer/<?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?>"> <?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?> </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

to display the manufacturer in the front end, but it is showing the same brands in all the sites.

how could I tell magento to show different brands on the different sites?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$attribute->getSource()->setStoreId($yourStoreId);
$manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I think big part of the problem is in the back-end, I mean there's no option there where you can define which manufacturer where to display... and that is sad!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether scope of the attribute "manufacturer" is set as "store view" or not